# PHP function : encode an array into JSON format Without get braces

Tags: php, json

How can I encode an array into JSON format Without get the left brace `{` and ends with the right brace `}`.

When I use the function below I get error:

> JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

in my Android app .so I can't get a listview from my database.

```
public function View()
{
    $con=$this->connect();
    if($con != null)
    {
        $result=$con->query(Constants::$SQL_SELECT_ALL);
        if($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $items_list=array();
            while($row=$result->fetch_array())
            {
                array_push($items_list, array("id"=>$row['id'],"item_name"=>$row['item_name'],"item_description"=>$row['item_description'],"item_image_url"=>$row['item_image_url']));
            }
            print(json_encode(array_reverse($items_list)));
        }else
        {
        }
        $con->close();

    }else{
        print(json_encode(array("PHP EXCEPTION : CAN'T CONNECT TO MYSQL. NULL CONNECTION.")));
    }
}
public function handleRequest() {
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $this->insert();
    } else{
        $this->select();
    }
}
}
```

Any idea how can I do that ?

Comment: Your PHP code looks basically OK, I think your app's Java code is where you need to look for the problem. One point about that code I do notice, though, is that the arrays you're encoding are numeric arrays, so in JSON they will not start with curly-braces anyway: they will be like `[item1,item2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ltrim, check this and see if work for you :)

ltrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string, more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

```
$array = array('id' => 123, 'item_name' => 'Some example', 'item_description' => 'Another example');

$json =  json_encode($array);

echo ltrim($json, '{');
```

The resultant string is

```
"id":123,"item_name":"Some example","item_description":"Another example"}
```

Comment: What does ltrim do? How does it help OP? Add some explanation with your answers!